# C# - Creating controls dynamically and accessing them

Tags: c#, dynamic-controls

I'm creating a simple notepad type of application with the tab functionality. I'm creating the TabControl, its TabPages and RichTextBoxes at run-time. I have them instantiated at class scope. And there is a MenuStrip item called New, by clicking that you can add more tab pages.

```
TabControl tbcEditor = new TabControl();
TabPage tbPage = new TabPage();
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();

private void frmTextEditor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Controls.Add(tbcEditor);
     tbcEditor.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     tbcEditor.TabPages.Add(tbPage);
     tbPage.Controls.Add(rtb);
     rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}

private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //TabPage tbPage = new TabPage();
     //RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();

     tbPage.Controls.Add(rtb);
     rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     tbcEditor.TabPages.Add(tbPage);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is a bit difficult to explain. I'll try my best. When the form loads, everything works as expected. The TabControl creates with a TabPage with a RichTextBox added. However if I click that New button to add another page, it goes bonkers. A new TabPage gets created but without a RichTextBox added. No errors are thrown either. If I un-comment out those 2 lines(under MenuItem click event), which creates 2 instances of TabPage and RichTextBox, everything works as I want.

Now my first question is why do I have to make new instances of only those 2 types(TabPage, RichTextBox) again but not TabControl? As you can see in the last line, I can use `tbcEditor` once again. But not `tbPage` and `rtb`.

Sure I can go on declaring them again at local scope but another issue arises then. If I want to say, add copy, paste functionality, I should do something like this,right?

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(rtb.SelectedText);
```

But I can't access `rtb` since it is declared as local.

I'm very baffled by this so any suggestions, ideas on how to overcome these 2 issues would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`If I un-comment out those 2 lines(under MenuItem click event), which creates 2 instances of TabPage and RichTextBox, everything works as I want.`

When you uncomment those lines, you are adding the same instance of the rich textbox and tab page to the container panel again which is meaningless. Instead add new controls foreach tabpage. (I hope thats the requirement)

`Now my first question is why do I have to make new instances of only those 2 types(TabPage, RichTextBox) again but not TabControl?`

TabControl is the parent control which has TabPages as child controls. You can have multiple tabs under one TabControl. So you need not create TabControls other than the `tbcEditor` you have already added. We do not add container controls more than once (unless its the requirement). Do we need more forms? No, just one form which can hold all the child controls right. Similarly just one TabControl which can hold a collection of TabPages. You would need more TabControls only if you want sub-tabs foreach new tab which I guess is not the requirement..

`But I can't access rtb since it is declared as local.`

This is no big deal. You can do in two ways:

1) Search for your appropriate control by looping. The [SelectedTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx) property gives what you want.

```
 private void someEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {           
        foreach (Control c in tbcEditor.SelectedTab.Controls)
        {
            if (c is RichTextBox)
            {
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(((RichTextBox)c).SelectedText);
                break; //assuming u have just one main rtb there
            }
        }
 }
```

2) Tag each rtb to the tabPage when you create it, and then you can get the tag element of the selected tab page to get the rich text box. I would go for this approach.

**Edit:** (In general pls make the following changes too to your code):

```
 TabControl tbcEditor = new TabControl();

 private void frmTextEditor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Controls.Add(tbcEditor);
      tbcEditor.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      AddMyControlsOnNewTab();
 }

private void AddMyControlsOnNewTab()
{
    TabPage tbPage = new TabPage();
    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
    tbPage.Tag = rtb; //just one extra bit of line.

    tbcEditor.TabPages.Add(tbPage);
    tbPage.Controls.Add(rtb);
    rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}

private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddMyControlsOnNewTab();
}
```

Now, you can call it like this:

```
 private void someEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {           
        RichTextBox rtb= (RichTextBox)tbcEditor.SelectedTab.Tag;
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(rtb.SelectedText);
        //or even better in just a line,
        //Clipboard.SetDataObject(((RichTextBox)tbcEditor.SelectedTab.Tag).SelectedText);
 }
```

What you have to consider here is which is the control that you first get and which is the one you do not get. You would get TabPage anyways but not the RichTextBox. So you have to tag RichTextBox to TabPage. You have to cast it since [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) is of type object, so you have to specify which kind of object it is. Finally, this method has the advantage that you need not loop through a list, so its more performant. And that you can have more RichTextBoxes in the TabPage (provided you want to copy text from only one set of RichTextBoxes, one from each TabPage)..

Comment: This assumes he is accessing the selected tab, which is reasonable assumption, but not defacto. If he is, for example, swapping text between tabs (or whatever action that requires access to unselected tabs, and not via an event callback), then it may be expensive to iterate through all tabs and controls therein (or not - numbers determine). Also, don't like using Tag proerty personally if I can help it, apart from the fact it needs casting, it does not make for clear code IMHO. Another old way is to use a naming convention so tabs can be linked to child controls by name "TAB_1" "TAB_1A"

Comment: Tag method is the best. It doesnt make readability tough if u know to read it, which is fairly easy. In fact Tags are indeed there to tag an object to instances of controls. I still dont get what's so expensive about loopin thru default Controls list of .Net than a plain list of controls. If he needs to select and copy text from rich text box, then its a valid assumption that he needs it from active tab. Even if its not, its just little tweakin of the above logic. I am wondering isn't it more work to get the rich text box field of any tab if one is maintainin just 2 separate lists of controls

Comment: I have and probably will again, use the Tag. I just don't see it's need here (and I think its a hangover that is still useful sometimes - like ArrayLists and some other 1.1 implimentations). If we are only interested in the selected tab, then we can just grab the first child control by index 0 - or use the name property (as it says what it is on the tin). I'm not trying to get into a peeing match, just interested really.

Comment: Ok here are the needs of a tag:

1. He needn't loop thru controls. Really good. Any tab, anywhere, he has the rich textbox connected to that page!

2. what if there are more than one rich textboxes in a tab page? how can the tool know from which text box of a page should it grab the selected text? Association is a good way of coding in these scenarios

Comment: Of course two child textboxes would also make using the Tag of the parent difficult - which one to add? I do see where you are coming from, and I have used it before myself (although not for a while). The question you posed is one that would set the design of the solution - I can't answer "what if" because I'm not the Op. I can think of several potential solution to that as I am sure you can to.

Comment: @Wolf5370 (sorry I forgot to mention you by name til now :) ) I assumed, reasonably, that only one Control is associated with a tab page, but there can be more controls of the type Control in that tab page. Its pretty reasonable. Anyway there is another use too for tags. I dont even understand how these things are obsolete for u

Comment: nawful: Not the Tag pe say, but the use of them as indexers (or holders) or children. I used this very commonly in the old 1.1 days (in asp.net mostly). I just don't seem to need it now very often at all. I also do not use external lists (as per the above) either for that - just seemed to fit in how I interpreted the problem at hand (and given the lack of usage info). It is probably me that got the wrong end of the stick problem wise. I could have written a long code section covering all the issues you mentioned, but this is not school, it's a pointer, a starting point.

Comment: Ok, so out of curiosity, let me ask you, how do you tackle requirements like these in .net 2.0 to .net 4.0 era? Tagging is what I have seen everywhere.

Comment: @Wolf5370 in fact as much as I gathered information about it, its pretty much the standard way to go. I mean tagging.

Comment: hey @nawfal, first of all, thanks a lot for the answer. :) It is very helpful. I tried your #1 method and it works a treat. But I'm interested in trying out the #2 approach too. However this I'm pretty confused about how this `tag` property works. Is this the correct way to tag the rtb? `rtb.Tag = tbPage;` or is it the other way around?

Comment: @nK0de It is the other way round. let me update the answer for you. that is pretty much simpler.

Comment: @nawfal, yes, I have only 1 RichTextBox per TabPage. I'm facing a  small issue here. I'm getting a _Object reference not set to an instance of an object_ error at `Clipboard.SetDataObject(((RichTextBox)tbcEditor.SelectedTab.Tag).SelectedText);`. What's the object do I have to instantiate?

Comment: @nK0de Just debug to see which object is null. You can see it when hitting a breakpoint. I assume its because the event calling this is doing it before richtextbox or tabpage is initialized. Which event is being triggered to set clipboard data?

Comment: Please ensure only after tabpage and richtextbox is created that the event is initialized. Otherwise there is no richtextbox to get selected text from. Or else you can add a return statement after a null check in the event function. Just a matter of choice

Comment: @nawfal you're right. I made some changes in the events. Now everything's working perfectly! Thank you very much for all the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The commented lines are doing just what they are suppposed to do. The code does not associate the Richtextbox with the Tabpage .

```
TabPage tbPage = new TabPage(); // Creates a new tabpage

RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox(); // Creates a new RichtextBox control.
```

TabControl is a container , so one instance is just fine.

Also see this - http://sujay-ghosh.blogspot.in/2009/03/addingremoving-dynamically-created.html, nothing with do with tabcontrols, but how to create controls on the fly.

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
tbPage.Controls.Add(rtb); 
rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
tbcEditor.TabPages.Add(tbPage);
```

Takes your exisitng textbox, adds it to the exisitng tab page, then adds that existing tab page to the editor.  Since this has already been done, nothing happens.

When you add those two lines, you create new instances of the text box and a new tab page, which is exactly what you want.  Your latter problem comes, because the newly declared variable `rtb` hides the one declared in the class -- in a different method you can only access the onde declared in the class (barring getting the control out of the tab)

To get around not being able to access the proper text box, you can maintain them in a list(*) (or some other collection) and refer to the one associated with the currently active tab.  For this, you will have to create an event listener to see which tab is activated currectly.

(*) as opposed to having only one

Answer (score 0):

OK you need to create fresh instances of the RichTextBox rathere than trying to add the same instance to each tab.

```
 TabControl tbcEditor = new TabControl();
 //Get rid off this line --- TabPage tbPage = new TabPage();
 //Get rid off this line --- RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();

 List<TabPage> _tabs = new  List<TabPage>();
 List<RichTextBox> _tbx = new  List<RichTextBox>();

 private void frmTextEditor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
      Controls.Add(tbcEditor);
      tbcEditor.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

       AddNewTab();
 }

 private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {   
       AddNewTab();
 } 

 private void AddNewTab()
 {
    //TabPage 
        var tbPage = new TabPage();
        _tabs.Add(tbPage);

        //RichTextBox 
        var rtb = new RichTextBox();
        _tbx.Add(rtb);

        tbPage.Controls.Add(rtb);
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tbcEditor.TabPages.Add(tbPage); 
 }
```

This simply add both the tab and the rtb to a collection which can be accessed by index (can also use Dictionary for named access etc). There are other ways of course, including just nameing the components and looping through for them when required etc.

Comment: There is absolutely no need of two member variables and cache UI controls here what so ever! :)

Comment: I disagree with that as a global statement. As I said, you could loop through (as your answer later states too) - or with List controls (and I doubt he actually wants/needs the TabPage one in the long run) he can go straight to it. It all depends on how many controls and what performance he wants. There are many ways to skin a cat and only he knows which will suit him best.

Comment: Looping is not the issue wolf here. He has to. In fact he need not do even that (the best approach in my option 2). But why create a separate list of UI controls when the very instance of the form itself holds all its controls? I mean isn't it better to loop through controls of tabpage rather than separately created redundant list? Tell me one good use of having separate list? Now leave that, tell me with your how are you going to detect the selected tabpage by looping through list?

Comment: I was not saying that looping is a bad solution (it can be if there are many controls and performance is an issue) - I am not even saying which is the best approach (I will maintain that that depends on the use required and not highlighted by the Op) - All I was saying was that a cartblanche dismissal of using a separate reference list is not correct. There are often times when maintaining a list of references is better than looping through a whole collection to find it. Is direct (Ok indirect indexed) access never better than sequential search?

Comment: In this problem, we could just as easily use the controls collection as you (I think) suggest. However, from the question in the Op, it seemed to me he was asking about addressing the controls directly from outside of specifying event callbacks. It seemed too obvious to me that he would ask how to access the control in a callback that identifies it (or its parent). This is why I offered the above solution (and stated that it can also be done with a search loop to). It all depends on the context of nthe problem at hand, and how we interpret the question I guess.

Comment: //There are often times when maintaining a list of references is better than looping through a whole collection to find it. //

Is this one? He would not need to loop thru all the controls in the form. All he would need is to loop  thru controls of a tabpage!! Thats too less a performance hit. How is a function "GetAnyRichTextBox'sTextWhichIDoNotKnowWhereItIsOrWhichTextBoxItIsFrom()" going to work? Thats why I say he would never loop through all controls. That's not in my code too.

Comment: He would need text from a specific textbox which he should be able to specify. And by the looks of it, its most certainly from the active tab. Hence looping thru one tab to find his rich text box is no big deal.  How is mine sequential and yours indexed? I agree there is an index for a list, but how can you specify the index? How on earth to know the index of a specific tab page or rich textbox from a long list of controls?? In fact do you know its easier to specify the index of control.Controls considering we can know what the index of a specific control in a container can be!!

Comment: Now this is not the heart of the discussion too.. How are you going to get a textbox of a specific tabpage? How can he specify a tabpage when all he has is a list of tabpages? meaningless. The only way out is to maintain a dictionary than a list.. All which requires the same sequential search, extra baggage - redundant built in controls method and an extra member variable. My Summary: there are cases where looping thru a list is better than looping thru controls, but not a realistic chance of it in the above question!!

Comment: Again, I just interpreted the question differently from you. I interpreted it that he wanted to access the controls externally form being the sender of an event. The indexing was not relevent to me as I have no idea how he wants to address them - I only offered a solkution to his immediate problem and covered his second question - how he would address them would I supposed be his starting point of the question (i.e. he starts with a way of addressing them and then needs a way to make such an address work) - hence a dictionary

Comment: ...(I used list as it was easier given the lack of that index mechanism but mentioned dictionary). You took the question to refer to how do I access the child control of a triggered tab - and thus offered a solution to cover that. As they are different solutions to different issues, I don't expect them to match. As I said, I was just interested in your use of Tag property (as I thought that an obsolete method these days). Sorry if you took that as a challenge, it was not meant to be.

Comment: Haha, we both interpreted it different, but I would say there's very less chance for what you are talking. very slim realistic chance.